# How to add x-axis ticks and labels bellow every point in a ggplot2 scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Let's say I have this plot

```
iris2 <- iris %>% data.table
iris2 <- iris2[Sepal.Length<6]
iris2[,Sepal.Width:=mean(Sepal.Width),by=Sepal.Length]
iris2 %>% ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,color=Species,group=Species)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Which renders:

[image]

How can I add axis ticks and labels so that for every point there is a corresponding tick and label?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `scale_x_continuous` to achieve what you want since your x axis is not discrete. The following code should work:

```
iris2 %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, group = Species)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(iris$Sepal.Length))
```